# I saw "StarHub Hybrid ..." media notification on my Android phone

Tags: notifications, android-tv, media-player

I saw a notification on my phone with media buttons (pause, forward, backward, etc...) that said "StarHub Hybrid ..." and some other stuff. I accidentally swiped the notification away immediately.

Does this mean that someone managed to connect a smart TV or something else to my Android phone, without me doing anything? I don't even use that Android phone as my primary phone, it's connected to my Mac all day, just sitting on the table, I'm using it to debug my Android app.

Comment: If I remember correctly from my personal experience living in a share house, this could happen when both an Android device and an Android TV are connected to the same WiFi. The Android device will show the media control even if the Android device is not casting anything, but acting only as a remote control.

Answer (score 1):

Smart TVs or TV "boxes" don't connect to Android phones, it's the other way around.

[StarHub indeed has one of those devices](https://www.starhub.com/personal/tvplus/box.html). They typically can be controlled or cast to from smartphones but they don't actively seek devices in the network for that purpose.

Considering you mentioned "media buttons" then it's reasonable to assume your phone is casting to a Starthub device. Knowing that such situation never happens without user intervention then we must conclude that either you or someone else with access to your (unlocked) phone must have started the cast. It can happen as easily as tapping the Youtube's cast icon and then the TV or StarHub receiver.

Another possibility is what @AndrewT. mentioned in a comment:

> The Android device will show the media control even if the Android
> device is not casting anything, but acting only as a remote control.